# 'void com.getcapacitor.Bridge.onStart()' on a null object reference

Tags: capacitor

I am wrapping a React application into Capacitor. When I run it from AndroidStudio the application starts and stops immediately. I receive the following.

```sh
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 20226
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.getcapacitor.Bridge.onStart()' on a null object reference
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.onStart(BridgeActivity.java:124)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8019)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

It seems that something absent. I checked tutorials. @capacitor/core is present.

Comment: In my case @capacitor/core  was absent. I tried the second time. It started working.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can you explain how is fix in detail, please? This is my capacitor version 

"@angular/router": "^9.1.12",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.4.2",

Comment: Can you elaborate @victor-shelepen please?

Comment: How can I help you?  The solution is too easy.  You need to recheck.

Comment: In my case @capacitor/core was absent, I checked twice.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by downgrading `@capacitor/cli` to `v2.4.5`.

```
npm i @capacitor/cli@2.4.5
```

I was facing issue with `v3.0.1`.